# Pattern matching for character and end of line

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string which is in following format:

```
I am extracting this Hello:A;B;C, also Hello:D;E;F
```

How do I extract the strings `A;B;C` and `D;E;F`?

I have written below code snippet to extract but not able to extract the last matching character `D;E;F`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Hello:).*?(?=,)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` means end-of-line.

Thus this should work:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Hello:).*?(?=,|$)");
```

So you look-ahead for a comma or the end-of-line.

[Test](https://ideone.com/OAo4lC).

Comment: Thanks for comment Dukeling, but that doesn't work. Infact it doesnt't match even A;B;C.
And yes I am looking for , or end-of-line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String test = "I am extracting this Hello:Word;AnotherWord;YetAnotherWord, also Hello:D;E;F";
// any word optionally followed by ";" three times, the whole thing followed by either two non-word characters or EOL
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+;?){3}(?=\\W{2,}|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
Word;AnotherWord;YetAnotherWord
D;E;F
```

Comment: Mena,actually A B C can be any other normal characters. those can be words as well.

Comment: @Brinal right. See my edit. If alnums are not enough you can also use Unicode categories.

Comment: I think your having the count of 3 matches. If my string is 
String s="I am extracting this Hello:Word;AnotherWord;YetAnotherWord,YetYetAnotherWord also Hello:D;E;F" it doesn't work.

Also it does not match "Hello" in particular. I wanted it to match particular tag.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mean omitting certain patterns in a string:

```
    String s = "I am extracting this Hello:A;B;C, also Hello:D;E;F" ;
    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

    tokens.add( "A;B;C" );
    tokens.add( "D;E;F" );

    for( String tok : tokens )
    {
        if( s.contains( tok ) )
        {
            s = s.replace( tok, "");
        }
    }
    System.out.println( s );
```